# Display image from server in a div (newest first) PHP

Tags: php, html, css

I want to display images in from server. In the database you can find the description and name of the image. the images should be displayed in a div where always the newest is on top. As the number of images increase so does the number of div's. so, the oldest will be at the bottom. I have read a number of posts and forums but I was unable to get the logic and the code on how to do it. I hope you can help me with my problem. Thanks a lot for your answer.

the only code i have is the formatting of the dive's:

```
<div class="gallery">

    <div class= "group">
        <div class="images">
        </div>

        <div class="details">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class= "group">
        <div class="images">
        </div>

        <div class="details">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class= "group">
        <div class="images">
        </div>

        <div class="details">
        </div>
    </div>

 </div>
```

it's something like this:

newest image     |       some details here

newer image      |       some datails here

new image        |       some details here

old image        |       some details here

**EDIT 1**

I combined Lauri Elias' and iamde_coder's answer. I come up with this code which works almost similar to what is wanted. the only problem is that it displays the item (image&details in a div) 4 times. How can I eliminate the three? thanks!

```
$image_query = mysql_query ("SELECT filename, story FROM tbl_contest ORDER BY time DESC");
  while($image_data = mysql_fetch_array($image_query)){
     $imageName = stripslashes(mysql_real_escape_string($image_data['filename']));
     $imageDetails = stripslashes(mysql_real_escape_string($image_data['story']));

  $count = 0;

foreach($image_data as $imageName) { 
    echo '<div class="group">';
    echo '<div class="images"><img src="/Mainfolder/image_entry/'.$imageName.'"></img></div>';
    echo '<div class="details">'.$imageDetails.'</div></div>';
    $count ++;
}
}
```

Comment: where is your code to fetch the images from database ?

Comment: You just need to use an  `ORDER BY ` in your MySQL query, and order by ImageDate. Then just use a for loop in php to loop through the already ordered records. Optionally you can sort the fetched data with php, but I would do that on the DB server instead.

Comment: @Hanlet thanks for you answer! I will try the logic you suggested and keep you posted to what happens. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that you've given a little more code to help try using this:

```
$count = 0;
$image_query = mysql_query ("SELECT filename, story FROM tbl_contest ORDER BY time DESC") or die(mysql_error());
while($image_data = mysql_fetch_array($image_query)){
 $imageName = stripslashes(mysql_real_escape_string($image_data['filename']));
 $imageDetails = stripslashes(mysql_real_escape_string($image_data['story']));
 $count++; 
 echo '<div class="group">';
 echo '<div class="images"><img src="/Mainfolder/image_entry/'.$imageName.'" alt="Image '.$count.'" /></div>';
 echo '<div class="details">'.$imageDetails.'</div></div>';
}
```

Comment: how can i sort the images? thanks for your answer :)

Comment: Hi! it's not displaying anything... what do you think im doing wrong here? and if another image is uploaded, how can the div's like increment? thanks

Comment: Where are the images stored on your server? are they in a folder named 'imagefolder'?

and did you change any of the coding around to fit your server/MySQL?

another possibility is if your php and image folder are in the same directory, for that, change the `<img src="../imagefolder/` to `<img src="imagefolder/`

Comment: Yes i changed the code to whereever it really is in my database and server. I have the ImageName as filename and the ImageDetails as story. the images are in a different folder which is named image_entry.

Comment: Hi @iamde_coder! i have combined your answer with Lauri Elias' answer. and i come up with something almost doing the expected result. the only problem is that it's displaying an item 4 times. the first two looks well and the second two doesn't show the image as if the link says it's forbidden. can you help me sort it out? every item should only be displayed once. thanks! i have edited my question for you to see my code.

Comment: Try using my edited code and see if that does it. The problem was, for each while loop, you'd have a foreach loop run a couple times making 4 of the same image/details.

Comment: thank you so much @imde_coder.. it's working properly now! thanks again :)

Comment: You should point out that `mysql_*` functions are deprecated and inherently insecure. OP should replace them with `mysqli_*` or switch completely to PDO and prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

You could, for example, use a MySQL select somewhat like this:

```
SELECT name, description FROM my_database.images ORDER BY created_at DESC;
```

Then bind the result set to a variable in PHP like $images and then iterate on it and generate HTML like this:

```
foreach($images as $image) {
  echo '<div class="group">';
  echo '<div class="images"><img src="/images_folder/'.$image['name'].'"></img></div>';
  echo '<div class="details">'.$image['description'].'</div></div>';
}
```

Comment: Hi @Lauri thanks for your answer. i will try it now. I'll keep you posted

Comment: i tried your code but it's not displaying anything. this is how i perform my query. what do you think i'm doing wrong with it?

    $image_query = mysql_query("SELECT filename, story FROM tbl_contest ORDER BY time ASC");
while($image_data = mysql_fetch_array($image_query)){
       $imageName = stripslashes(mysql_real_escape_string($image_data['filename']));
       $imageDetails = stripslashes(mysql_real_escape_string($image_data['story']));

Comment: In your updated question you are probably iterating on the items in a bit of a wrong way. mysql_fetch_array should return an array of all the images, see if it's true by writing `echo var_dump(mysql_fetch_array($image_query));` Then place the result in a variable and foreach on the mofo, generating the HTML.

Comment: i tried to echo var_dump(mysql_fetch_array($image_query));
what it's printing is something like 

array(4) { [0]=> string(28) "20131030040845-img_entry.jpg" ["filename"]=> string(28) "20131030040845-img_entry.jpg" [1]=> string(332) "My super story begins with a call from someone. sometexthere" ["story"]=> string(332) "My super story begins with a call from someone. My task was to book a flight to Dubai at a cheaper cost.chorva chorva c. " }

Comment: i tried `echo $imageName;` then it's returning all the imagenames already sorted.